# Occasional bug then clicking the close or flag buttons

Tags: bug, user-interface

I am browsing via Firefox 45.8.0. I have had a number of occasions, starting in the last day or so, when clicking on the "Flag Answer" and "Close" has taken me to the pages of companies advertising jobs. Here is an example:

[image]

In the image above, when I click on the button immediately after taking the screenshot, a new tab opens to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/bloomberg, and the flagging dialog disappears without raising the flag.

This only seems to happen when a company ad is under the button. The bug can be reproduced by refreshing the page a number of times until such an ad comes up, then trying to flag or close a post.

The only workaround I have been able to find is to use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys to navigate to the appropriate button after making my selection ("very low quality" in the picture above).

Comment: Wait, I can't just close my own post? I have to vote to close it as a dupe?

Comment: If the vote button isn't over an Ad ...